# $2x_1 + 2x_2 + \cdots + 2x_6 + x_7 = N$

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

How do I find the number of integral solutions to the equation -

$$2x_1 + 2x_2 + \cdots + 2x_6 + x_7 = N$$

$$x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_7 \ge 1$$

I just thought that I should reduce this a bit more, so I replace $x_i$ with $(y_i+1)$, so we have:

$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_6 = \tfrac{1}{2}(N + 13 - y_7)$$

$$y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_7 \ge 0$$

I will be solving this as a programming problem by looping over $y_7$ from $[0, N+13]$. How do I find the number of solutions to this equation in each looping step?

Comment: I think it's a polynomial of degree $5$ in the $y_i$s. The number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 = a$ is $a+1$, so the number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = b$ is $\sum_{i=0}^b (i+1) = $ a quadratic polynomial etc.

Comment: Please see the Wikipedia article on Stars and Bars. It may be useful to compute the required binomial coefficients iteratively.

Comment: Consider using \ldots and \cdots to get ellipsis instead of three full stops. They give $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $x_1+\cdots+x_n$ instead of $x_1,...,x_n$ and $x_1+...+x_n$. The command \ldots gives low dots and the command \cdots gives centre dots.

Comment: You had $2y_1 + 2$ on the left, so you subtracted $2$ to get $2y_1;$ you needed to _subtract_ $2$ from the right side as well, but you _added_ $2.$ Similarly for the other $y_i,$ so instead of $N + 13$ you should have $N - 13.$ The idea was a good one, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $x_7$ must be either odd or even depending on whether $N$ is odd or even. So if you just subtract $1$ from $N$ if necessary and assume $x_7 = 2y$ where $y \geq 0$, then you get that the number of solutions is the same as the number of solutions to $x_1 + \ldots + x_7 = N/2$ where $x_i \geq 1$ for $1 \leq i \leq 6$ and $x_7 \geq 0$. This can be solved with a single binomial coefficient (no big summation required), see the "stars and bars" construction for how to do it, basically you just add 1 to the target sum $N/2$ for each variable that is $\geq 0$ instead of $\geq 1$, and then if you have target sum $M$ and $k$ variables all $\geq 1$ then the number of solutions is ${M-1} \choose {k-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{0 < a < 1}$:

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{x_{7} = 0}^{\infty}
> \delta_{2x_{1} + \cdots + 2x_{6} + x_{7},N}}
> =\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{x_{7} = 0}^{\infty}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}
> {1 \over z^{-2x_{1}\ -\ \cdots\ -\ 2x_{6}\ -\ x_{7}\ +\ N\ +\ 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{N + 1}}
> \pars{\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}z^{2x}}^{6}\sum_{y = 0}^{\infty}z^{y}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{N + 1}}\,{1 \over \pars{1 - z^{2}}^{6}}\,
> {1 \over 1 - z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{N + 1}}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-6 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}z^{2n}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}
> {6 + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}
> {1 \over z^{N - 2n - k+ 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
> {n + 5 \choose n}\delta_{k,N - 2n}
> =\left.\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + 5 \choose 5}\right\vert_{\,N\ -\ 2n\ \geq\ 0}
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\floor{N/2}}{n + 5 \choose 5}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\floor{N/2}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n + 5} \over z^{6}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{5} \over z^{6}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\floor{N/2}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{5} \over z^{6}}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{\floor{N/2} + 1} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{\floor{N/2} + 6} - 1 \over z^{7}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> -\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{5} \over z^{7}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\color{#00f}{\large{\floor{N/2} + 6 \choose 6}} - {5 \choose 6}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{{\pars{\floor{N/2} + 6}\pars{\floor{N/2} + 5}
> \pars{\floor{N/2} + 4}\pars{\floor{N/2} + 3}\pars{\floor{N/2} + 2}
> \pars{\floor{N/2} + 1} \over 720}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$x_{7}=2k+1  , x_{7}=2k \\ partition - by - x_{7}\\2x_{1}+2x_{2}+2x_{3}+...+x_{7}=N\\(1) x_{7}=2k+1 ,    2x_{1}+2x_{2}+2x_{3}+...+2k+1=N\\2x_{1}+2x_{2}+2x_{3}+...+2K=N-1\\if -(N-1) - was- even -divide - by -2\\x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+K=\frac{N-1}{2}\\\binom{\frac{N-1}{2}-1}{7-1}\\ \\(2) x_{7}=2k ,    2x_{1}+2x_{2}+2x_{3}+...+2k=N\\if\\N \\was\\even\\divide -by -2 \\x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+K=\frac{N}{2}\\\binom{\frac{N}{2}-1}{7-1} $$